# How to read text from balloon popup window using python?

Tags: python, bluetooth, balloon-tip

I am transferring a large file of about 500MB using bluetooth from one system to another. During this time I will get a balloon popup window saying "Bluetooth Connection" having a text that the mode has changed to high speed mode. I want to get this text in a variable using python. Any clue about how to read text from balloon popups???

Hope to get a reply asap.

Regards 
Sim

Comment: hwat is you use? linux windows? what is balloon?

Comment: i think windows stores information about those balloon popups temporarily in some internal file, but i doubt you would have read permissions, maybe try a different approach? like perhaps checking the bluetooth program itself for any files or temps that inform of the functionality, maybe hook onto the process of the bluetooth?

Answer (score 5):

I combined posts of [here](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=10639) and [here](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/000664.html) to write the following example for you.

You need Python for Windows extensions which you can download [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

You can get the classname (you need it for the function win32gui.FindWindow) of your balloon tip, with the tool [Spy++](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.co.at/2010/11/microsoft-spy-or-spyxx-for-download.html).

```
import win32gui, win32con

def get_text(hwnd):
    buf_size = 1 + win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
    buffer = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(buf_size)
    win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, buf_size, buffer)
    return buffer[:buf_size]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("tooltips_class32", 0)
    content_of_balloon_tip = get_text(hwnd)
    print content_of_balloon_tip
```