# How to read text from another window with python

Tags: python, gettext

Hi I need help to achieve this I have reviewed posts like this:
[How to read text from balloon popup window using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771936/how-to-read-text-from-balloon-popup-window-using-python)
But I have not been successful. I'm too new.

What I actually need is very similar to this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353050/can-i-read-text-from-another-window-using-java#:~:text=interface%20User32%20extends,Native.toString(lParamStr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353050/can-i-read-text-from-another-window-using-java#:%7E:text=interface%20User32%20extends,Native.toString(lParamStr)))%3B%0A%20%7D

But in python

Comment: Did this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862454/get-text-from-popup-window solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I saw it, Thank you very much. You can please move your comment to a response to be RESOLVED

Comment: See the answers in this post, may help you :
[Get text from popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862454/get-text-from-popup-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import time
import win32gui

while True:
  window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
  title = win32gui.GetWindowText(window)
  control = win32gui.FindWindowEx(window, 0, "static", None)
  print ' ', win32gui.GetWindowText(control)
  time.sleep(1)
```

Source : [Get text from popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862454/get-text-from-popup-window)